# looping in primitive array android java

Tags: java, android

I've tried to looping JSONArray to put it's value into primitive array, but the result always **null**, here's my code (**code 1**):

```
        try{
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(str);

           /for(int i=0;i<=data.length();i++)
           {
               JSONObject videos = data.getJSONObject(i);
               videoListData = new VideoData[]{new VideoData("aaa",getBitmap(videos.getString("url")))};
           }
            VideoAdapter adapter = new VideoAdapter(videoListData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've tried to put it without looping and successful, here's my code (**code 2**):

```
VideoData[] videoListData = new VideoData[]{
            new VideoData("Email", getBitmap("xaf234")),
            new VideoData("Info", getBitmap("xaf290")),
            new VideoData("Info", getBitmap("1f7ucv5"))
```

**Q** : How to implements **code 2** in looping?

please help

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a new array **every time** you loop. That's not what you want to be doing; you want to **add** to the array every loop.

Java arrays are fixed size and you need to know the size beforehand. Hence, don't use them; use ArrayList instead.

Thus:

```
List<VideoData> videoListData = new ArrayList<VideoData>();

// the rest of your code, except...

videoListData.add(new VideoData("aaa", getBitmap(...));
```

Comment: Completion(if question initiator need data as Array, instead of List) : `VideoData[] videoDataArray = (VideoData[])videoListData.toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are assigning new value every time, but you need to add data in your videoListData, like
videoListData.add(new VideoData("aaa",getBitmap(videos.getString("url"))));